# "this.jdbcTemplate" is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc

I am trying to use SpringBoot to update my Java Database Class but getting the error in the title.

I am sharing the code for Pom.XML and Employee Repository Class , what do I need to change?

I added values in the application.properties part and also added the @Autowired notation but nothing works.

Thank you and apologies for any inconvenience in advanced.

```
    package org.Name.EmployeeManagement.Repository;
     
    import org.Name.EmployeeManagement.Models.Employee;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
     
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.UUID;
     
    @Repository
    public class EmployeeRepository{
     
        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
     
        @Autowired
        public void setJDBCTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
            this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
        }
     
        public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(){
            return this.jdbcTemplate;
        }
       
        public Employee getInformationAboutEmployee(String name){
           String sql = "Select * from Employee Where name = " + name;
           return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql,Employee.class);
        }
        public String insertValuesIntoTable(String name,String phoneNumber){
            String sql = "INSERT into Employee(id,name,phoneNumber) values (?,?,?)";
            int result = jdbcTemplate.update(sql, UUID.randomUUID(),name,phoneNumber);
            if(result>0) return "Successfully Updated";
            else return "Failure";
        }
    }
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>org.Username</groupId>
        <artifactId>EmployeeManagement</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>EmployeeManagement</name>
        <description>Project for Employee Management</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>17</java.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
                <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
                <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
     
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
     
    </project>
```

Comment: is there a bean of that type provided?

Comment: @Stultuske I don't think so.

Comment: in that case you can't autowire it

Comment: @Stultuske how should I solve it then? I am new to spring boot and still figuring out the annotations part.

Comment: A field in Spring cannot be `null` , if Spring fails to fullfil a dependency it will not even start the application and fail with an error. If it is `null` you are creating an instance yourself probably outside the scope of Spring. Also use constructor injection instead of field or setter injection for required dependencies. Finally remove the `version` tags from the `pom.xml` in your `dependencies` section, Spring Boot will manage those for you. Will save you headaches in the future when upgrading.

Comment: Can you share your application.properties

Comment: @Daksharajkamal yes , wait let me share.

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/EmployeeManagement
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password = password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
logging.level.root=INFO